# Set java32 bit as must in install4j

Tags: install4j

We have install4j version 5.1.5 we have set min Java Version as 1.8 , but on 64bit jvm there is issue with wrapper.dll loading .

Can we set jdk platform i.e 32bit or 64 bit along with min Java Version

Answer (score 0):

On the "32-bit or 64-bit" step of the Windows media wizard, you decide whether executables should be generated as 32-bit or 64-bit executables.

Comment: once executable are generated it check for min jdk 1.8 is installed or not .

Comment: Yes, the executable only uses a JRE with the configured minimum version

Comment: Re add:
once executable are generated it check for min jdk 1.8 is installed or not . I want to set it to check for jdk32 bit version only on 32 bit as well as 64 bit machine

Comment: A 32-bit launcher only works with a 32-bit JVM and a 64-bit launcher only with a 64-bit JVM, so there is no "bitness" checking at runtime.

Comment: But here  exe is generated as installer and its is working with both ... and later when starting app .. it throws wrapper.dll error

Comment: Maybe the bitness of the media file and the wrapper.dll do not match

Comment: Yes , any idea how can I include both dll (32 & 64 bit ) in same installer

Comment: See https://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/helptopics/concepts/files.html